# Functions whose Fourier coefficients satisfy $ \sum_{k=1}^\infty |c_k| < 1 $?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $f:(0,1) \to \mathbb R$ be a function that can be written as  $$f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k \phi_k(x),$$ where $\phi_k(x) = \cos(\pi k x)$. What is the minimal assumption required on $f$ to obtain
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty |c_k| < 1 \ ?
$$

As pointed out in the comments below, this is related to characterizing the functions in the unit ball of the Wiener algebra.

I am aware of the estimate $|c_k| \lesssim k^{-m}$ if $f \in C^m(0,1)$, but I'm looking for something more precise as above.

Comment: The sum looks like the norm of $f$ in the [Wiener algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_algebra), so I believe any space that embeds into the Wiener algebra with an explicit constant will give you a sufficient condition, and other than that not much can be said.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki I don't know exactly what you mean.

Comment: If $f$ is extended to an even $2$-periodic function, then the sum $\|f\|_{\mathbb A} = \sum_k |c_k|$ is the norm of $f$ in the Wiener algebra $\mathbb A$ (up to multiplication by a constant, perhaps). So the condition $\|f\|_{\mathbb A} < 1$ describes the unit ball in the Wiener algebra $\mathbb A$. Now we know, for example, that if $\alpha > \frac12$, then the space $C^\alpha$ of Hölder-continuous functions with exponent $\alpha$ is contained in $\mathbb A$ when $\alpha > 1$, with $\|f\|_{\mathbb A}$ bounded by a constant $C_\alpha$ times the Hölder norm $\|f\|_{C^\alpha}$. (1/2)

Comment: Therefore, if $\|f\|_{C^\alpha} < 1 / C_\alpha$, then of course $\|f\|_{\mathbb A} < 1$. If we knew the value of $C_\alpha$, this would give a sufficient condition you are looking for. The constant can be found by inspecting the proof of Bernstein's theorem mentioned above. See, for example, Zygmund's *Trigonometric series* (one of the online sources I found mentioned it is on page 241 of the 1988 edition). (2/2)

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Which Hölder space are you considering: $\alpha > 1/2$ or $\alpha >1$ (which only contains constants)? Unfortunately, I don't have access to that book: what is the constant $C_\alpha$?

Comment: Ah, sorry for the typo: $\alpha > \tfrac12$, of course. Regarding the constant: no idea, I did not follow the steps of the proof. You can find it, for example, in [Albin Petersson's degree project](https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1323350/FULLTEXT01.pdf), see Theorem 3.1 there.

Comment: "Laplacian with Neuman boundary conditions" is a fancy way to say that $\phi_n(x)=\cos\pi n x$?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Yes

Comment: $f=g+h,g(0)-h(0)<1$ and $u\to u\ast g,u\to u\ast h$ both semidefinite positive $L^2(\Bbb{R/2\pi Z})\to L^2(\Bbb{R/2\pi Z})$

Comment: @reuns I don't understand what you mean